# How to highlight checkbox pseudo element which substitutes hidden checkbox input, when it required

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a checkbox pseudo element which substitutes hidden checkbox input, and I want to highlight it when hidden checkbox is required. Is there any *css* solution? What is the right way to solve problem?
https://jsfiddle.net/ht2c9sbd/3/

```
<form>
  <div class="group-input">
    <input type="checkbox" id="c_1" required hidden="">
    <label for="c_1">I agree with everything.</label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

css:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 0 14px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: calc(50% - 15px);
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s ease, border-color 0.25s ease;
    transition: background-color 0.25s ease, border-color 0.25s ease;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(20, 61, 139, 0.2);
    margin: 0 14px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    top: -2px;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
    background-image: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/447/447147.png);
    background-size: 15px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(20, 61, 139, 0);
    background-color: rgba(20, 61, 139, 0.2);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

here is my horrible js solution:

```
function checkCheckbox(e) {
    if (!e.checked) {
        $('head').append('<style id="invalidCheckbox">input[type="checkbox"] + label::before {border: 1px solid #ff3535; box-shadow: 0 0 2px #ff3535;}</style>');
        return false;
    } else {
        let temp = $('head style:last');
        while(temp && temp[0].id === "invalidCheckbox"){
            temp.remove();
            temp = $('head style:last');
        }
        return true;
    }
}

const mycheckbox = document.getElementById('c_1');
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  checkCheckbox(mycheckbox); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script:

```
const mycheckbox = document.getElementById('c_1');
document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if ( mycheckbox.hasAttribute('required') && !mycheckbox.checked ){
    mycheckbox.className = "invalid-input"; // <-- add new class
  } else {
    mycheckbox.className = "";
  }
});
```

Style (you can change style as you want) :

```
input[type="checkbox"].invalid-input + label::before{
  background-color: red;
}
```

> Try to update the existing DOM element instead of creating a new element in DOM because DOM manipulation is slow.
>
> A repaint occurs when changes are made to an elements skin that changes visibly but does not affect its layout.
>
> Create new DOM element is even more critical to performance because it involves changes that affect the layout of a portion of the page

Answer (score 0):

To highlight a `required` checkbox:

**In CSS:**

```
/* Style (any) element with the required attribute: */
:required {
  background: red;
}

/* Style input elements with the required attribute: */
input:required {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(200, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

/* Style focused and required element: */
input:required:focus {
  border: 2px solid red;
  outline: none;
}

/* Style hover and required element: */
input:required:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**In JS:**

```
// Get the element
var req = document.getElementById("my_checkbox").required;

// Check if required
if(req.hasAttribute('required')) {

    // Style it
    req.style.background = "red";
}
```